# Linear algebra clearing fractions method

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Where I'm I going wrong, i'm clearing the fractions, and from what I can tell i've done something wrong. That must be from the distributive property.

$$
  - \dfrac{149}{16} - \dfrac{11}{3}r = -\dfrac{7}{4}r-\dfrac{5}{4}(-\dfrac{4}{3}r+1)
$$

$$
 - \dfrac{149}{16} - \dfrac{11}{3}r = - \dfrac{7}{4}r + \dfrac{20}{12}r - \dfrac{5}{4}
 $$

$$
- 447 - 176r = - 84r + 60r - 60
$$

$$
-447 - 176r = 24r - 60
$$

$$
 -447 = 200r - 6
$$

$$
-387 = 200r
$$

$$
\dfrac{-387}{200} = r
$$

Expected answer is -9/4

Comment: It looks like you made a multiplication mistake when multiplying by the greatest common denominator to get line 3: $\frac{20}{12}$ and $\frac{5}{4}$ should give different answers when multiplied by the GCD, since they're different to start with.

Comment: To clear the fractions I did $...=7(48/4)r+20(48/12)r-5(48/4)$, i see  20(48/12) = 80

Answer (score 1):

You should check your way of taking LCM. After solving you will get-

> $$ - \dfrac{149}{16} - \dfrac{11}{3}r = - \dfrac{7}{4}r + \dfrac{20}{12}r - \dfrac{5}{4} \implies - 447 - 176r = - 84r + 80r - 60 $$